# How to return a Ruby float with 2 decimal places when displaying currency

Tags: html, sql, ruby

I have an SQL database storing prices passed in from floats in a Ruby Class that I then need to subsequently display in an HTML/erb file. My problem is that price that is 10.00 or 10.20 returns as 10.0 or 10.2, this then displays incorrectly in HTML. I need the prices to remain as floats in Ruby as they are being used for calculations... is there an obvious way to return these prices at 2 decimal places?

I've attempted to store them differently in my SQL database and I believe I could try to convert the float to a string and split it on the decimal point then loop over the second element in that array and add another zero if a single digit, then put the array back together as a string - but I'm struggling to get this to work...

My Ruby class is set up like so:

```
class Transaction

  attr_accessor :amount, :merchant_id, :tag_id, :transaction_date
  attr_reader :id

  def initialize(options)

    @id = options['id'].to_i if options['id']
    @amount = options['amount'].to_f
    @merchant_id = options['merchant_id'].to_i if options['merchant_id']
    @tag_id = options['tag_id'].to_i if options['tag_id']
    @transaction_date = options['transaction_date'] if options['transaction_date']

  end
```

The SQL table likewise:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
  id SERIAL8 PRIMARY KEY,
  amount DECIMAL(10,2),
  transaction_date DATE,
  merchant_id INT8 REFERENCES merchants(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  tag_id INT8 REFERENCES tags(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When I run my debugger on the array of values I return everything is displaying as a float as per how I've defined it in my class...

Comment: **Never ever store currency as floats.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond the very valid comment of not storing currency as floats, you are where you are, so to display the number with 2 decimal places you need to use http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

```
[1] pry(main)> sprintf('%.2f', 2)
=> "2.00"
[2] pry(main)> sprintf('%.2f', 2.569)
=> "2.57"
[3] pry(main)> sprintf('%.2f', 2.56)
=> "2.56"
[4] pry(main)> sprintf('%.2f', 2.56666666)
=> "2.57"
```

So in your code:

```
class Transaction

  attr_accessor :amount, :merchant_id, :tag_id, :transaction_date
  attr_reader :id

  def initialize(options)
    @id = options['id'].to_i if options['id']
    @amount = sprintf('%.2f', options['amount'].to_f)
    @merchant_id = options['merchant_id'].to_i if options['merchant_id']
    @tag_id = options['tag_id'].to_i if options['tag_id']
    @transaction_date = options['transaction_date'] if options['transaction_date']
  end
```